# Gradle not including one dependency when creating the artifact

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle in an IntelliJ project to manage dependencies in a Spring project to provide REST web services. As long as I run the project in the IDE it works fine, but if I execute the `java -jar artifact.jar` command it cannot start. The following error is printed

```
13:42:47.338 [main] WARN org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Unable to close ApplicationContext
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.(...).web_services.JmsConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:914)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:902)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:889)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:830)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:349)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
            at com.(...).web_services.WebServicesApplication.main(WebServicesApplication.java:10)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/ConnectionFactory
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
            ... 21 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
            ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I suppose the `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` class comes with the Spring ActiveMQ package, and I already tried to update Gradle manually but that did not solve the problem. Also importing `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` in the JMS class did not help. Any clue?

Comment: I don't use gradle but in maven there is an option to compile a "fat jar" (a jar including all the dependencies). I'm sure there's the same thing in gradle.

Comment: About the problem itself, your jar depends on some other jars (here on javax.jms which declares the class ConnectionFactory). When you're on the IDE, the jar is already downloaded on your local repository and provided at runtime so the code runs fine. But when you run the jar with java -jar, there is no dependency context so either you have them somewhere else provided in your system, or (like in your case) you want your app to be standalone and so all external dependencies should be physically packaged in your "fat" jar.

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar), it should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ on the contrary, if I try to run the fat jar the error shown is a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Comment: then it's not a fat jar you are running :) if you unzip the jar do you see all the dependencies (for example a folder org that contains a folder springframework etc) or just the classes of your project?

Comment: you're right, I only see my classes here. but I created that jar following the section 4 of the guide, creating a dedicated gradle task. Any suggestion?

Comment: Honestly I really don't know Gradle. The only thing I can suggest is you look for "build fat jar with Gradle" on the web and try all you find until you manage. To make it easier, once you package Spring & co. the jar becomes pretty big. I have a project which makes a jar of 100 KB, when I compile it with Spring the jar becomes about 23MB. Hence keep on testing until you don't see your target jar really inflating (and the right way to check is always to open it as zip and make sure you have all the external classes packaged along).

Comment: i started running a bunch of random gradle tasks in desperation and apparently the buildDependents one creates a working .jar, ~30MB. I don't know what changes but this one looks to work properly. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: Great that worked. I suggest you post the change you did as an answer and accept it yourself, so that if some day someone will have the same problem and find your answer, they will know straight what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first attempt was to create a fat jar using the following custom gradle task (as suggested by @MatteoNNZ following [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar)).

```
task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': '<myPackage>.<myMainClass>'
    }
    baseName = 'all-in-one-jar'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

However, as this didn't work, I ran the predefined gradle task buildDependents that created a working .jar in the `build/libs` folder.